# Integrating Slack into Nuke

Tags: python-2.7, slack, nuke

I have a slack push notification code which executes by itself but when I import this script into nuke's menu.py - it throws me an error

```
"ImportError: No module named slackclient"
```

Again, python script for slack notification works when it is executed by itself and issue is when i call this through nuke.

I'm new to programming in python and trying this out as a fun project on the side.

```
# python 2.7     
# code used for notification 

from slackclient import SlackClient

def slack_message(message, channel):
    token = /token/
    sc = SlackClient(token)
    sc.api_call('chat.postMessage', channel=channel, 
                text=message, username='test_bot')

slac_message("Test msg", "general")
```

Answer (score 0):

The module is called `slack`, not `slackclient`. So the correct statement is:

```
from slack import SlackClient
```

Also make sure you have [version 1](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/tree/v1) of the slackclient package, since the current version 2.x is for Python 3.6+ only.

Comment: Thanks Erik. The link you shared for  slackclient v1 recommends to use "from slackclient import SlackClient" also, this piece of code executes with no error by posting message on slack, but when I try using it within a different application ends up with an  import error

Comment: ok sorry. Its how it works with the version 2, but apparently not in version 1 then.